# Java: ZonedDateTime - get the offset of a reference timestamp

Tags: java, datetime, zoneddatetime

I have a timestamp in UTC. I convert it into localtime. My timezone is CET/CEST.

```
2018-10-03 12:00 UTC => 14:00 CEST
2018-10-30 12:00 UTC => 13:00 CET
```

Because of my timezone the system automatically applies the correct offset: If I convert timestamp in summer it automatically adds 2hrs (no matter what time it is when I convert), if it is in winter it adds 1hr.

So far - so good.

Now I would like to convert a UTC timestamp based on another referenced timestamp. 
If the reference is in summer it should always add 2hrs - no matter if the timestamp to convert is summer or winter - and if reference is in winter it should always add 1hr.

```
Ref = 01.01.2018 = CET
2018-10-03 12:00 UTC => 13:00 CET
2018-10-30 12:00 UTC => 13:00 CET

Ref = 01.10.2018 = CEST
2018-10-03 12:00 UTC => 14:00 CEST
2018-10-30 12:00 UTC => 14:00 CEST
```

So how can I find out what timezone (or what offset to UTC) a reference timestamp (in UTC) has if my systems runs normal CEST/CET??

I use ZonedDateTime normally.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `ZoneId` from the reference `ZonedDateTime` that you have and use it to adjust the timestamp that you have in `UTC` to that zone:

**Set up**

```
    ZoneId cet = ZoneId.of("CET");

    // The reference timestamps, these could be any ZonedDateTime
    // but I specifically make one for winter and one for summer
    ZonedDateTime refWinter = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-01-01T12:00"), cet);
    ZonedDateTime refSummer = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-10-01T12:00"), cet);

    // The UTC timestamp that you want to convert to the reference zone
    ZonedDateTime utc = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.parse("2018-10-03T12:00"), ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

---

**Conversion**

```
    // The converted timestamps
    ZonedDateTime convertedWinter = utc.withZoneSameInstant(refWinter.getOffset());
    ZonedDateTime convertedSummer = utc.withZoneSameInstant(refSummer.getOffset());

    System.out.println(convertedWinter); // 2018-01-03T13:00+01:00
    System.out.println(convertedSummer); // 2018-10-03T14:00+02:00
```

Answer (score -2):

You can parse your date from string to Date object if they are in UTC and then you can convert them back to the string in your local timezone. Please check below code  example:

```
        SimpleDateFormat isoFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date = isoFormat.parse("2018-10-03 12:00");

        isoFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        System.out.println("Date in my local timezone is "+isoFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: You shouldn't use the `Date` class in new code. Use the classes from the new Date and Time API available in the `java.time` package.